# How to create a lookup field from another lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, column

I have one lookup column. I need to create another lookup column to look up the existing lookup column in different lists.

I am notable to do this, Could you please suggest some idea to implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to lookup an existing Lookup column in different lists.

As a workaround, I suggest you create another column which is used to store the lookup column's value, you can use a workflow to set the column to the lookup's value and automatically start the workflow when an item is created and changed.

Then in the target list, lookup the new column instead of the existing lookup column.